# How to reinstall android contacts application to replace original one for debug?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I modified contacts application codes based on android 2.3, and compiled as the Contacts.apk, then I push it to system/app/, but the contacts application disappears in the Launcher, then I re-install it, i got INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE, how to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Andoid creates "shared users" for packages you install. Sometimes the administration of these shared users gets messed and you get:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE
```

The shared user administration is kept in `/data/system/packages.xml`:

How to solve? You need a rooted phone and adb:

```
adb shell su -c "chmod 666 /data/system/packages.xml"

adb pull /data/system/packages.xml
```

Now take a backup copy of the file and then edit the file and remove the shared user from the file:

```
<shared-user name="com.your.target.app" userId="10000">
<sigs count="1">
<cert index="4" />
</sigs>
<perms>
<item name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<item name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<item name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<item name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<item name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<item name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<item name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<item name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<item name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<item name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<item name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<item name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
</perms>
</shared-user>
```

Then copy modified file back:

```
adb push packages.xml /data/system/packages.xml

adb shell rm /data/dalvik-cache/*

adb shell su -c reboot
```

**EDIT**
Another thing is, you need to sign the apk with the same certificate with other installed application if it has a shared user id. But usually it is not possible to obtain that certificate from phone manufacturer.

In that case, you can try to open manifest file and find:

```
android:sharedUserId="some_string"
```

and change it with something different. Rebuild apk, clean out packages.xml, reboot and install again.

Comment: After reboot, I re-install Contacts.apk, also get INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

Comment: the Contacts AndroidManifest.xml:     android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shared" What can I change it to?

Comment: it doesn't matter. It's just a string, simply change it to something different such as "com.victor.s"

Comment: I had tried according to your solution step by step, but I also get INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE, maybe the apk needs to be signed or any other something?

Comment: in that case, i guess you need to sign the apk with the device system certificate